# How to edit magento2 footer section?

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, design, footer, edit

I want to edit the footer section in entire site. How can I do that. Further when we go to `store-> configuration -> design` from admin panel we can edit the design. 
Where is it going to apply as I cannot see the changes I have done through that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit magento 2 footer section using Block in **`luma`** theme,
 go to admin panel ,

```
Content -> Block -> Footer Links Block
```

You can also changes same as in magento1,
Go to `Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Design -> Footer tab`
and set html inside `Miscellaneous HTML` textbox.

Also some footer links comes from xml files,

```
Privacy-cookie: magento2/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
Search Terms : magento2/vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
Contact: magento2/magento/module-contact/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
Advance search: magento2/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
Order Returns: magento2/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

Comment: by default there is no Footer Links Block there

Comment: which links you have to customize? plz give me name for that

Comment: for about us and customer service block comes from Footer Links Block.

Comment: i have updated answer.